# Separating large dataframe in R with multiple integers in each column, then summing integers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R that I read in from a text file with two columns that each have multiple integers per value. I need to subtract the corresponding integers from one column (Start) from the corresponding integer in the other column (End). What I ultimately want to get for the last step is to sum all of the distances to get on total distance for each track. The below dataframe is just an example but the one in question has about 20 integers per column and there are dozens of tracks (rows).

for track A: (15-6)+(20-5)+(7-1)

```
track     StartDist         EndDist
A         1, 5, 6           7, 20, 15
B         1, 7, 8, 11       6, 21, 22, 25
```

I would use the function `separate()` but there are not an equal number of integers per column. I also considered remaking the dataframe with each row containing only one integer but I would end up with thousands and thousands of rows and then would have to combine them back again to calculate their totals for each track. Any advice?

Comment: Making your 'long' file with each row containing only one integer is typically what I'd do. You can then simply do `End-Start` and calculate the sum per `track` group using any number of functions like `aggregate` in base R, dplyr's `group_by` or data.table's `by=` processing.

Comment: @thelatemail would love if you could expand this into a proper answer. This is a good question imo and an answer would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution. We group entries by `track` using `split`, then use a custom function `splt` to split entries in columns `StartDist` and `EndDist` by `", "`; we then calculate pairwise differences using `mapply` and return the sum of all pairwise distances in column `sum.diff`.

```
splt <- function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ", ")))

df$sum.diff = sapply(split(df, df$track), function(x) {
    start <- splt(x$StartDist);
    end <- splt(x$EndDist);
    sum(mapply(function(a, b) b - a, start, end)) });
df;
#  track   StartDist       EndDist sum.diff
#1     A     1, 5, 6     7, 20, 15       30
#2     B 1, 7, 8, 11 6, 21, 22, 25       47
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "track     StartDist         EndDist
A         '1, 5, 6'           '7, 20, 15'
B         '1, 7, 8, 11'       '6, 21, 22, 25'", header = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd really recommend storing this as a 'long' file to make any subsequent analyses a lot simpler. If you are in the tidyverse world, I'd do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

datlong <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(StartDist, EndDist), str_split, ",\\s+") %>%
  unnest %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(StartDist, EndDist), as.numeric) 

datlong %>%
  group_by(track) %>%
  summarise(Len = sum(EndDist - StartDist))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  track   Len
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1     A    30
#2     B    47
```

Where `dat` was:

```
txt <- "track|StartDist|EndDist
A|1, 5, 6|7, 20, 15
B|1, 7, 8, 11|6, 21, 22, 25"

dat <- read.table(text=txt, sep="|", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And a base R translation for fun and games:

```
vars    <- c("StartDist", "EndDist")
othvars <- setdiff(names(dat), vars)
dat[vars] <- lapply(dat[vars], strsplit, ",\\s+")

datlong <- cbind(
  dat[othvars][rep(seq_len(nrow(dat)), lengths(dat[[vars[1]]])),, drop=FALSE],
  lapply(dat[vars], unlist),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
datlong[vars] <- lapply(datlong[vars], as.numeric)

aggregate(cbind(Len = EndDist - StartDist) ~ track, data=datlong, FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution that also uses `stringr`. We use `rowwise()` and `mutate` to apply the following operations to *each* row: `str_split()` separates the string in each "Dist" column into a list of alphanumeric strings, which are then unlisted, coerced to numeric vectors, and subtracted in the order that you requested. The elements of the resulting numeric vector are then summed.

For what it's worth, I prefer base R solutions, so I think Maurits Evers' solution is more elegant:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

track <- c("A", "B")
StartDist <- c("1, 5, 6", "1, 7, 8, 11")
EndDist <- c("7, 20, 15", "6, 21, 22, 25")

df <- data.frame(track,StartDist,EndDist)

df <- mutate(rowwise(df),
             sum = sum(as.numeric(unlist(str_split(EndDist, ","))) - as.numeric(unlist(str_split(StartDist, ",")))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  track StartDist   EndDist         sum
  <fct> <fct>       <fct>         <dbl>
1 A     1, 5, 6     7, 20, 15       30.
2 B     1, 7, 8, 11 6, 21, 22, 25   47.
```